# Can't access dynamic routes and error page in next js

Tags: javascript, next.js

Whenever I set proxy to backend api in next.config.js, dynamic routes and error page can no longer be accessed

```
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:slug*',
        destination: 'http://localhost:5000/:slug*', // backend url
      },
    ]
  },
```

With the above set up, dynamically routing to [id].js gives cannot get...

Routing to random routes (routes not in my page) give cannot get... Instead of my 404.js (error page)

When I have the rewrites commented, everything works fine.

Is there something I'm doing wrong

Comment: Shouldn't the source be `source: '/api/:slug*'` if you want to rewrite API calls only? As you currently have it, everything is getting mapped to your backend API.

Comment: Oooh! i get. so as to differentiate frontend url from api url right. but i do not have /api in my api url. i might have to add it then and give it a try. Thanks Juliomalves

Comment: You don't need to have `/api` in your actual API endpoints, though. When using `source: '/api/:slug*'`, you would just use `/api/whatever-endpoint` as the URL when making the request from the client-side. That would then proxy to `http://localhost:5000/whatever-endpoint` in your API.

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Comment: But does it work for? Can't have my error page anymore and my dynamic page [id].js does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you getting an error? How are you making the request from the client-side?

Comment: Nop. No error. Just getting "Cannot get" the page I route to, error page and dynamic page

Comment: All these work when I comment out the rewrites in next config file

Comment: There's no error

Comment: Just that I cannot get those pages,

Comment: Did you change the source to `source: '/api/:slug*'` as I suggested? Did you restart the dev server after making the changes to `next.config.js`?

Comment: I will need to have it this way right: ```source:"/api/:slug*", destination:"http://localhost:5000/:slug*"```

Comment: I did it this way, restarted, same thing

Comment: ```source:"/api/:slug*", destination:"http://localhost:5000/:slug*" ``` . With this, I got error "404 Page not found"

Comment: What path are you trying to access? Is that an expected 404? What were you expecting to see if not?

Comment: Nop. querying an api to get results. 404 doesn't come if added the api to the routes in the backend